# Question turns out to be a bug, will never have an answer

Tags: discussion

I'm looking for advice from some senior members on what to do here

After much troubleshooting & updates I was able to reproduce the problem entirely on a fresh new database. It truly was a bug/error, nothing was wrong on my end.

[Ms Access Web DB (Access Services) GotoControl functionality broken](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128520/ms-access-web-db-access-services-gotocontrol-functionality-broken)

Since it is a bug, I realize now that the question will never have an answer unless the bug is fixed.

I don't want to delete it though, in case anyone else runs into same issue. In fact, while doing more research I continually saw my own question here on SharePoint Stack Exchange come up in the top search results.

Is it okay to leave a question unanswered? If this will affect the Question:Answer ratio here at SP.SE I'd be happy to delete the question. I have a blog I could post my findings at, so they would not be lost.

Please advise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not answer the question? Stating in the answer that there is a reproducible bug with no current solution? That would be helpful for future readers