# What kind of excuse is this for closing a question?

Tags: discussion

It's as simple as honey, if you don't know the answer leave the question alone, let someone else who knows or in future knows the solution answers it,

[Do we must need to add hnsc address to host files?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131157/do-we-must-need-to-add-hnsc-address-to-host-files)

> Voting for close as it is Visual Studio bug and there already is a
>   workaround. Please contact Microsoft Support regarding the issue and
>   for ETA on the fix. –  Jussi Palo 1 hour ago

What kind of excuse is this for closing a question ?

Comment: I think that should be an answer, not a reason to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Any user with enough reputation can vote to close a question. It will then start a process where at least 4 more users (or 1 moderator) gets the chance to agree or disagree with the user asking for the question to be closed.

This is how this community works, and how it should work. Moderators should not intervene in this if there is not clear signs of a pattern where some user targets questions written by another user or in other way behaves in an incorrect way.

As you can see, your question is not closed, nor has it been closed. So the system seems to be working just the way you want it to?

Answer (score 1):

A visual studio bug is a valid answer, if in fact the issue arises from a bug in the product. See [related](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/question-turns-out-to-be-a-bug-will-never-have-an-answer) meta article. Like all software, some bugs persist longer than others and it is really up to the authors to address the bugs in a timely manner. It might not be a priority for them to fix.

But to Robert's point, this is how the system works. Not enough people agreed with him, or a mod, to close your question.

Comment: I partially agree with you, some bugs are so deep technical that all you can do is just wait till product vendor fixes it, but maybe I couldn't explain it in right words in the question, I was after answer telling me this is how visual studio detects the web application, however I did my own research and figured out why visual studio was failing and explained to system admin, I'll update my post.